# Ursprung der stimmhaften Aussprache von <s>

Tags: pronunciation, dialect, regional, middle-high-german, old-high-german

In zahlreichen Büchern über historische Sprachstufen des Deutschen (z. B. *Alt- und Mittelhochdeutsch* von Bergmann/Pauly/Moulin) wird darauf hingewiesen, dass die beiden Grapheme <s> und <z> wahrscheinlich nur durch den Artikulationsort unterschieden wurden. Ersteres Graphem ist das alte aus dem Urgermanischen ererbte *s;* das zweite Graphem ist der aus der zweiten Lautverschiebung entstandene stimmlose Frikativ, der zum heutigen *ss* bzw. *ß* wurde. Wenn ich die Literatur richtig interpretiere, war die Aussprache des <s>-Graphems also [s] (oder zumindest ein anderer stimmloser Sibilant). Vereinzelt findet sich im Internet der explizite Hinweis, dass <s> im Alt- und Mittelhochdeutschen **stimmlos** war.

Heute gibt es im Neuhochdeutschen (mindestens) zwei Positionen, wo <s> **stimmhaft** ausgesprochen werden kann:

1. Am Wortanfang vor Vokalen (z. B. *Sonne*)
2. Im Wortinneren zwischen Vokalen (z. B. *Hase*)

Es hängt von der Sprecherherkunft ab, in welcher der beiden Positionen das <s> stimmhaft realisiert wird. Grob eingeteilt ergibt sich folgende Verteilung:

- Im *Norden* des deutschen Sprachraums: **1. = stimmhaft** und **2. = stimmhaft**
- Im *Südosten* (bairischer Dialektraum):  **1. = stimmlos** und **2. = stimmhaft (mancherorts)**
- Im *Südwesten* (alemannischer Dialektraum): **1. = stimmlos** und **2. = stimmlos**

**Meine Frage:** Wo<sup>1</sup> und wann<sup>2</sup> entstand die stimmhafte Aussprache von <s> und wie kam es zu dieser geographischen und positionellen Verteilung?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Bzw. im Kontakt mit welcher Sprache ist sie entstanden? (Kontakt mit Niederdeutsch? Kontakt mit Französisch?)</sub>

<sup><sup>2</sup> Im Althochdeutschen, Mittelhochdeutschen, Frühneuhochdeutschen oder Neuhochdeutschen?</sup>

---

Meine eigene Hypothese (die ich jedoch nicht belegen kann) ist, dass sich das stimmhafte *s* vom Niederdeutschen ins Hochdeutsche schlich, als sich das Hochdeutsche nördlich der Benrather Linie ins niederdeutsche Sprachgebiet ausbreitete. Hierzu fehlen mir aber die Quellen und wissenschaftlichen Nachweise.

Answer (score 3):

Wie bei den anderen Reibelauten nimmt man heute an, dass auch bei der Entstehung des stimmhaften 's' das Vernersche Gesetz gilt:

> Im Zusammenhang mit der germanischen Konsonantenverschiebung ist das ‚Vernersche Gesetz‘ zu sehen: Die neu entwickelten germanischen stimmlosen Reibelaute f, þ, χ **und das ererbte s** bleiben nur dann erhalten, wenn (im Indogermanischen) der
>   Hauptton unmittelbar vorausging. In allen anderen Fällen wurden die Reibelaute stimmhaft und in der Folge im Deutschen zu stimmhaften Verschlusslauten b, d, g bzw. s zu r. <sup>Polenz: Deutsche Sprachgeschichte 2009</sup>

Für die genaue linguistische Beschreibung der Lautentwicklung zum stimmhaften 's' ist aber erschwerend, dass diese keinen Eingang in die Schriftsprache gefunden hat, und dass diese Entwicklung regional stark unterschiedlich war. So beschrieb [Ludwig Sütterlin](http://books.google.de/books?id=0q4soWedKW4C&lpg=PA77&ots=8oOcv76DoH&dq=stimmhafter%20%22s-laut%22%20lautverschiebung&pg=PA77#v=onepage&q=stimmhafter%20%22s-laut%22%20lautverschiebung&f=false)

> Da die zweite Lautverschiebung in den einzelnen Gegenden Deutschlands ganz verschieden gewirkt hat, klingen die Konsonanten selbst im Munde der Gebildeten bei den gleichen Wörtern heute noch lanschaftlich sehr verschieden.Vor allem kommt dabei die Abweichung in Betracht, die hinsichtlich der Stimmhaftigkeit bei mehreren Arten von Kosnonanten zwischen Niederdeutshcland und Hochdeutschland besteht. [...] Ähnlich liegen die Verhältnisse bei dem alten, auf germanisches s zurückgehenden s-Laut. Im Beginn eines Wortes und ebenso im Inlaut bei stimmhafter Nachbarschaft spricht der Norddeutsche stimmhaftes *z* *(zaen, haozes)*, der Mittel-und Süddeutsche stimmloses *(sain, hauses)*. [...] Die Bühne hat überall den norddeutschen Gebrauch angenommen.

Die Annahme, dass das stimmhafte 's' über das Niederdeutsche Eingang in die "hochdeutsche" Bühnensprache Preussens und somit in die heutige Standardsprache genommen hat, ist vermutlich richtig.

Diese [Bühnensprache](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BChnendeutsch) wurde aber in weiten Teilen des deutschen Sprachraums nicht vollständig übernommen. So blieb das stimmlose 's' in Mitteldeutschland, Süddeutschland und auch in Österreich und der Schweiz erhalten.

Comment: Ich habe zwei Probleme mit deiner Antwort: (1) Im Wortinneren ist das Vernersche Gesetz für den _Grammatischen Wechsel_ verantwortlich. Ursprünglich standen 

sich (je nach Betonung) stimmloses _s_ und stimmhaftes _s_ gegenüber. Aus dem stimmhaften _s_ wurde in vielen Positionen ein _r_, sodass heute der 

Grammatische Wechsel zwischen (stimmhaftem) _r_ und stimmlosem _s_ auftreten müsste: _waren_ vs. _gewesen_. Nach deiner Erklärung müsste also das _s_ in 

_gewesen_ ein stimmloses sein. Das ist es aber nicht, sondern wurde (später, irgendwann nach dem V. Gesetz) zu einem stimmhaften _s_.

Comment: (cont) D.h. heute besteht ein Grammatischer Wechsel zwischen stimmhaftem _r_ und stimmhaftem _s_. Meine Frage bezieht sich gerade darauf, wie das stimmlose _s_, das das Vernersche Gesetz überlebt hatte und nicht zu _r_ wurde, zu einem stimmhaften _s_ wurde. (2) Am Wortanfang wurde nach dem Vernerschen Gesetz die stimmlose Variante fortgesetzt. Sonst hätten wir heute nicht den _Vater_ (_f_-Laut aus der stimmlosen Variante), sondern einen _Bater_. (Denn nach deiner Theorie: Am Wortanfang stimmhafte Variante, aus der sich zwischen dem Germanischen und Althochdeutschen ein _b_ entwickelt hat.)

Comment: (cont) Ein weiteres Beispiel: Der _Hund_ müsste _Gund_ heißen, wenn am Wortanfang die stimmhafte Verner-Variante gestanden hätte. Daraus kann man folgern, dass am Wortanfang nicht die stimmhafte Variante stand und somit der stimmhafte _s_-Laut in _Sonne_ etc. nicht per Verner erklärt werden kann.

Comment: @Chris: ich denke mittlerweile, dass man das nicht so genau weiß. Man könnte darüber promovieren oder sich habilitieren... jedenfalls wird meist schon ein irgendwie gearterter Zusammenhang mit dem Vernerschen Gesetz gesehen, das aber natürlich für das 's' nicht 100% gilt. Zumindest das Nord/Süd-Phänomen läßt sich aber mit Einflüssen des Niederdeutschen in die preussische Bühnensprache gut erklären.

Comment: @Chris: es wäre bestimmt auch eine Bereicherung, wenn du deine Recherchen und Überlegungen in eine eigene Antwort packst (evtl. kannst du dann auch Teile dieser Antwort, die schon in der Frage stehen, nach dort verschieben).

Comment: +1 für den Hinweis mit der preuß. Bühnensprache. Ich recherchiere übrigens immer mal wieder wegen meiner Frage und bin derzeit der Auffassung, dass die Stimmhaftwerdung von _s_ nicht wirklich etwas mit dem VG. zu tun hat, sondern ein Unterphänomen der _Spirantenschwächung_ ist. Leider finde ich keine eindeutige Datierung (von Nordwestgermanische Ursprache bis Spät-Althochdeutsch ist alles dabei). Auffallend ist übrigens, dass sich _h/ch_ aus der 1. Lautverschiebung ähnlich verteilt wie stimmhaftes/stimmloses _s_. Und die v-Schreibung des _f_-Lauts könnte auch damit zu tun haben.

Comment: @Chris: eine eigene Antwort, die du nach und nach mit weiteren Fakten füllst, wäre doch was... Schon deine Kommentare hier sind erste Klasse; man könnte sie direkt in eine Antwort c & p!

Comment: @Takkat Wo und wann wurde die Bühnensprache »gesetzlich verordnet«? Der verlinkte Wikipediaartikel schweigt sich zu dem Detail leider aus.

Comment: @jan das wäre eine schöne neue Frage (denn zu dieser Frage wäre das off topic).

Comment: @Takkat [Jo.](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/war-die-deutsche-b%C3%BChnenaussprache-jemals-gesetzlich-vorgeschrieben) ;)

Answer (score 3):

In der Sprachgeschichte des Deutschen gab es (mindestens) drei verschiedene Phänomene, bei denen ein stimmhafter *s*-Laut entstehen konnte:

1. Durch **Assimilierung** an einen anderen stimmhaften Konsonanten im Indogermanischen
2. Durch das **Vernersche Gesetz** beim Übergang vom Indogermanischen zum Germanischen
3. Durch die sogenannte **Spirantenschwächung** zu althochdeutscher Zeit

Ein Großteil der neuhochdeutschen stimmhaften *s*-Laute geht auf den letzten Punkt, die **Spirantenschwächung**, zurück.

---

**(zu 1.)** Bereits im Indogermanischen gab es ein stimmhaftes *s*, das jedoch nur vor anderen stimmhaften Konsonanten als Assimilierung auftrat (idg. **nizdos* aus **nisdos*, nhd. *Nest*). Es kann ausgeschlossen werden, dass es sich beim neuhochdeutschen stimmhaften *s* um diesen ererbten Laut handelt, weil es im Neuhochdeutschen hauptsächlich im Wortinneren zwischen Vokalen und am Wortanfang vor Vokalen auftritt.

---

**(zu 2.)** Die **Erste Lautverschiebung** markiert den Übergang vom Indogermanischen zum Germanischen; bei ihr spielen das **Grimmsche** und das **Vernersche Gesetz** eine Rolle:
Bei der Ersten Lautverschiebung wurden stimmlose Plosive zu Frikativen (dies ist ein Teil des Grimmschen Gesetzes). Zu diesem Lautwandel zählen:

- idg. *p* wird zu germ. *f*
- idg. *t* wird zu germ. *þ* (stimmloser *th*-Laut wie in engl. *thin*)
- idg. *k* wird zu germ. *χ* (stimmloser *ch*-Laut wie in nhd. *ach*)

Damit hatte das Germanische vier Frikative: *f*, *þ*, *χ* und ererbtes *s*.
Dem Grimmschen Gesetz folgt das Vernersche Gesetz: Abhängig von der Wortbetonung und der Position der Frikative blieben sie entweder stimmlos oder wurden stimmhaft; die stimmhaften Frikative entwickelten sich teilweise weiter zu stimmhaften Plosiven:

- germ. *f* bleibt *f* oder wird *β* (das zu *b* wird)
- germ. *þ* bleibt *þ* oder wird *ð* (das zu *d* und später zu *t* wird)
- germ. *χ* bleibt *χ* oder wird *ɣ* (das zu *g* wird)
- germ. *s* bleibt *s* oder wird *z* (das teilweise zu *r* wird)

<sup>Im Satz "bleibt *x* oder wird *y*" nenne ich im Folgenden *x* die stimmlose Verner-Variante und *y* die stimmhafte Verner-Variante.</sup>
Mit *z* ist hier der stimmhafte *s*-Laut gemeint. Das stimmhafte *s* in *Hase* kommt zum Beispiel von diesem Lautwandel. Viele stimmhaften *s* haben sich aber gewandelt zu einem *r*-Laut, z. B. in engl. *hare*. Deshalb können nicht alle stimmhaften *s*-Laute durch diesen Prozess erklärt werden: Teilweise kommen auch im gleichen Flexionsparadigma Formen mit beiden Verner-Varianten vor (*Grammatischer Wechsel*), z. B. in *sie waren* vs. *gewesen*. Das *r* in *waren* entstand aus der stimmhaften Verner-Variante, das *s* in *gewesen* kommt von der stimmlosen Verner-Variante. Nun wird heute das *s* in *gewesen* stimmhaft ausgesprochen, was alleine durch das Vernersche Gesetz nicht erklärt werden kann.

Des Weiteren kann das Vernersche Gesetz nicht das stimmhafte *s* am Wortanfang erklären: Hätte am Wortanfang die stimmhafte Verner-Variante gestanden, so hätten wir heute nicht das Wort *Vater* (kommt von germ. *f*), sondern *Bater*; und wir hätten nicht das Wort *Hund* (kommt von germ. *χ*), sondern *Gund*. Somit stand am Wortanfang die stimmlose Verner-Variante und damit auch stimmloses *s*. Stimmhaftes *s* am Wortanfang kann also nicht durch Verner erklärt werden.

---

**(zu 3.)** Der Großteil der heutigen stimmhaften *s*-Laute geht auf die sogenannte **Spirantenschwächung** zurück, die von verschiedenen Autoren verschiedentlich datiert wird: Damaris Nübling (*Historische Sprachwissenschaft des Deutschen*) legt die Spirantenschwächung ins Spätalthochdeutsche; Martin Findell (*Phonological Evidence from the Continental Runic Inscriptions*) stellt die Spirantenschwächung in den Nordwestgermanischen Tochtersprachen fest, z. B. im Althochdeutschen und Altsächsischen; Stefan Sonderegger (*Althochdeutsche Sprache und Literatur*) datiert den Prozess auf das Frühalthochdeutsche.

Die Spirantenschwächung betrifft die stimmlosen Frikative, die durch Verner nicht stimmhaft wurden, also *f*, *þ*, *χ* und *s*. Der *th*-Laut *þ* wurde im Althochdeutschen in den allermeisten Positionen zu einem *d*; man kann annehmen, dass ein Zwischenschritt über ein stimmhaftes *ð* wie in engl. *this* führte. Der *ch*-Laut *χ* wurde am Wortanfang vor Vokalen und im Wortinneren zwischen Vokalen zu einem *h*. Der *f*-Laut wurde am Wortanfang und zwischen Vokalen zu einem *v*-Laut, was sich noch heute an vielen deutschen Wörtern zeigt, die von einem germanischen *f* abstammen und mit *v* geschrieben werden (Vater, Vogel, ver-, Vieh, vier...). Bei diesem Prozess wurden also die stimmlosen Frikative am Wortanfang und zwischen Vokalen "geschwächt". Bei *f* und *þ* schlägt sich diese Schwächung in einer Stimmhaftwerdung nieder; bei *χ* wird der Reibelaut zu einem schwächeren Hauchlaut *h*. Leider hat sich die Spirantenschwächung nicht in der Schreibung von *s* niedergeschlagen, es ist aber anzunehmen, dass in ähnlichen Positionen das *s* ebenfalls "geschwächt" - also stimmhaft - wurde.
Die Spirantenschwächung im Überblick:

- ahd. *f* wird teilweise geschwächt zu *v*
- ahd. *þ* wird geschwächt zu *d*
- ahd. *χ* wird teilweise geschwächt zu *h*
- ahd. *s* (stimmlos) wird teilweise geschwächt zu *s* (stimmhaft)

Comment: Ja, aber. Es gab zwar im Spätalthochdeutschen die Spirantenschwächung, und in der Graphie ⟨v⟩ hat sich ein Rest davon in einigen Wörtern erhalten. Aber man wird keine Kontinuität zwischen der spätalthochdeutschen Spirantenschwächung und dem modernen norddeutschen [z] annehmen können: Das ⟨v⟩ wird ja heute stimmlos gesprochen; die südlichen Gegenden, die damals Spirantenschwächung hatten, haben heute stimmloses [s]. Ich vermute, das moderne norddeutsche [z] ist eine nördliche Eigenheit – vgl. niederl. [z] –, die seit etwa hundert Jahren als vorbildlich gilt (wie auch die Auslautverhärtung).

Answer (score -1):

I think nobody will answer your question in a way that is absolutely based on facts.
One can only guess. In earlier times the German-speaking population was not a homogenous body but an  agglomeration of various tribes as Franks, Saxons, Bawarians, Alemanni and others and their languages were different. This may be one cause that there are differences in pronunciation and intonation in various parts of the German speaking area.
Another cause may be influence of neighbouring languages. Everybody can hear that in Austria people speak with a different intonation, the German of Switzerland can be seen as a language of its own and a German hears whether a person is from Bavaria, Franconia, Hessen, Cologne, northern Germany or from Berlin. They all have their own peculiar speaking habits and we can describe them, but why they speak in this way that is beyond our knowing.

Comment: I do not think that this contains anything that Christ does not already know.

Comment: I'm not searching for _absolute facts_ but for the state of (scientific) knowledge. If there are guesses/hypotheses in textbooks, that's fine with me and their citation will be an answer I accept. All that I have found is the s-pronunciation in Old/Middle High German times and in modern New High German times. However, I haven't found any information of how the s-pronunciation changed in between. - And please consider my careful wording: I asked for _when_, _where_ and _how_ (descriptive). I am aware of the fact that _why_-questions often cannot be answered.

Comment: @rogermue: Damit die 50 Rep-Punkte nicht verfallen, habe ich sie dir zugeteilt, auch wenn ich mit der Antwort nicht wirklich zufrieden bin. ;-)