# War die deutsche Bühnenaussprache jemals gesetzlich vorgeschrieben?

Tags: pronunciation, history

In [einer früheren Version dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/15933/revisions) zu einer nur wenig verwandten Frage meinte Takkat:

> Diese, damals **teilweise gesetzlich verordnete** [Bühnensprache](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BChnendeutsch) wurde aber in weiten Teilen Deutschlands nicht vollständig übernommen. (Hervorhebung durch den Fragesteller)

Dieser Satz irritiert mich, und der verlinkte Wikipediaartikel schweigt sich zu diesem interessanten Detail aus. Meine Frage:

Wann, wo und für welchen Zeitraum wurde eine Aussprache – konkret die deutsche Bühnenaussprache – gesetzlich verordnet?

Comment: Leider kann ich meine Quelle, die ich zur damaligen Antwort studiert hatte, und in der eine teilweise gesetzliche Verordnung behauptet wurde, nicht mehr finden. Ich habe deshalb (und weil es dort auch nichts zur Sache beiträgt) meine hier zitierte Antwort angepasst.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wenn es um Gesetze geht, muss man immer streng nach Staaten unterscheiden. (Manchmal sogar auch innerhalb eines Staates nach Ländern.)

### Deutschland

Das ist das Land in dem der in Bremen geborene Mediävist, Mundartforscher, Volkskundler, Kirchenmusiker und Deutsch-Professor Theodor Siebs im Jahr 1898 gemeinsam mit wichtigen Theater-Vertretern (die wiederum auch hauptsächlich preußischer bzw. norddeutscher Herkunft waren) das Buch »**Deutsche Bühnenaussprache**« herausgegeben hat.

Dieses Buch erscheint erst seit seiner im Jahr 1969 herausgegebenen 19. Auflage unter dem heutigen Titel »**Deutsche Aussprache**«.

Da dieses Buch bis 1969 auch dem Titel nach nur auf Schauspieler und ähnliche Berufe abzielte, halte ich es für ausgeschlossen, dass es zwischen 1898 und 1969 als Grundlage eines allgemein gültigen Gesetzes verwendet worden wäre. Dennoch wurde die Anwendung dieser Aussprache auf vielen Theaterbühnen von den jeweiligen Direktoren vorgeschrieben.

Ich halte es für denkbar, dass die Lehrpläne einiger deutscher Bundesländer die Siebssche Aussprache im Programm hatten, und da die Lehrpläne zwar selbst keine Gesetze, aber dennoch amtliche Verordnungen sind, wohnt ihnen auch so etwas wie Gesetzeskraft inne. Diese Aufnahme in die Lehrpläne ist jedoch nur eine Vermutung von mir, und stellt auch schon das Maximum dessen dar, was ich dieser Aussprache als Gesetzes-Vorlage zutraue.

Dass Siebs' Aussprache im gesamten Gebiet des heutigen Deutschland in den Lehrpänen steht oder stand, bezweifle ich aber sehr, weil die Siebssche Aussprache auch innerhalb Deutschlands in großen Gebieten, vor allem im Süden, auf Ablehnung stieß und stößt. Siebs war Norddeutscher, der zwar auch einige Studienjahre in Tübingen zugebracht hat, sich sonst aber hauptsächlich in einem Gebiet aufgehalten hat, dessen Deutsch-Aussprache vom niederdeutschen Dialekt-Kontinuum geprägt war. In einer 1912 erschienenen Kritik wurde die von Siebs propagierte Aussprache als »geziert und lächerlich« beschrieben, wenn man versuchte, sie im Alltag einzusetzen.

Ein anderer Grund, warum ich es für ausgeschlossen halte, dass irgend eine Aussprache-Regelung Gesetzes-Status erreicht haben könnte, ist die zu erwartende Ablehnung durch die Bevölkerung, die sich dadurch bevormundet fühlen würde, noch dazu wenn keine gewichtigen Vorteile einer solchen Vorschrift zu erkennen sind.

### Österreich

Die Siebssche Aussprache wurde in der Vergangenheit, und wird auch in der Gegenwart, in Österreich als fremd empfunden und wurde daher nie an Schulen unterrichtet. Das trifft mit Sicherheit auf die Besatzungszeit (1945-1955) und auf die Zweite Republik (seit 1955) zu.

Ich weiß es nicht mit Sicherheit, aber glaube, dass man sich auch in der k.u.k. Monarchie (1867-1918) recht wenig um ausländische Regelungen gekümmert hat. Dasselbe dürfte auch für Deutschösterreich (1918-1919) und für die Erste Republik (1919-1938) gegolten haben.

Zwischen 1938 und 1945 gab es kein Österreich, und daher auch keine österreichischen Gesetze (das Gebiet des früheren und späteren Österreichs hieß damals »Ostmark« und war Teil des Deutschen Reiches).

In der Zeit, in der Wien, Salzburg, Graz usw. nicht in Österreich, sondern im Deutschen Reich lagen, wurde jedoch an den dortigen Schauspielhäusern und Theatern die Siebssche Aussprache als Standard-Bühnensprache eingeführt, und weder während der Besatzung durch die Alliierten Mächte, noch in der wiedererstellten Republik wieder abgeschafft. Daher hört man auch heute noch z.B. im Wiener Burgtheater eine deutsche Aussprache, die man sonst – mit Ausnahme anderer Bühnen wie z.B. auch der Staatsoper – nirgendwo in Wien hören kann. Dieser Umstand war auch immer wieder Gegenstand von zum Teil sehr heftiger Kritik.

Ich selbst bin zwar kein Schauspieler, singe aber in einem renommierten Wiener Chor (Wiener Singakademie), und wenn wir deutsche Texte einstudieren, müssen wir unsere österreichische Aussprache ablegen und alles nach den Vorgaben des Herrn Siebs aussprechen (eigentlich aus-singen).

Aber nachdem interne Regelungen von Theaterhäusern keine Gesetzeskraft haben, gilt dennoch, dass die Siebssche Aussprache in Österreich nie von einem Gesetz vorgeschrieben wurde.

### Schweiz

Die Siebssche Aussprache wird in der Schweiz sogar als bedeutend fremder empfunden als in Österreich. Ein erheblicher Teil der Schweizer mit der Muttersprache »Deutsch« gibt bei Befragungen an, Standarddeutsch (häufig auch als »Hochdeutsch« bezeichnet) wäre bereits die erste Fremdsprache, die Kinder ab dem ersten Schultag lernen müssten.

Der Gedanke, die Siebsschen Aussprache hätte es in der Schweiz jemals in den Rang einer gesetzlichen Vorgabe geschafft, erscheint geradezu absurd.

### Italien, Belgien, Luxemburg, Liechtenstein

In diesen Staaten (in Italien nur in Südtirol) ist Deutsch ebenfalls eine Amtssprache, allerdings ist mir nicht bekannt, dass jemals in einem dieser Gebiete eine Regelung der deutschen Aussprache auf gesetzlicher Ebene existiert hätte.

### Europäische Union

Auch in diesem Staatenbund ist Deutsch eine vom mehreren Amtssprachen. In der Europäischen Union ist de jure aber nicht einmal genau festgelegt, welche der drei deutschen Schrift-Standards die Amtssprache »Deutsch« sein soll, wobei das Schweizerische Deutsch ohnehin nicht in Frage kommt. (Die Schweiz gehört nicht zur EU.) De facto wird in amtlichen Schriftstücken der EU stillschweigend Deutsches Deutsch vorausgesetzt, Österreichisches Deutsch aber ebenso stillschweigend auch akzeptiert. Unter dieser Voraussetzung eine amtliche Normierung der Aussprache durchzusetzen, hat meines Wissens noch keine Fraktion versucht.

### Namibia bzw. Südwestafrika

Deutsch war auch in Südwestafrika Amtssprache, zwischen 1884 und 1915 sogar die einzige. Bei der Umwandlung des Staates in das heutige Namibia im Jahr 1990 wandelte sich der Status der Deutschen Sprache von einer Amtssprache zu einer Nationalsprache (anerkannte Minderheitensprache). Da aber das Namibia-Deutsch schon seit seiner Einführung als Amtssprache im Jahr 1884 sehr stark von zwei anderen Westgermanischen Sprachen, nämlich English und noch mehr von Afrikaans beeinflusst wurde, weicht auch seine Aussprache stark vom europäischen Deutsch ab. Siebs' Einfluss auf diese Varietät der Deutschen Sprache ist sehr gering, und war niemals auch nur in der Nähe von einer gesetzlichen Norm.

### andere Sprachinseln

Deutsch wird in vielen anderen Staaten auf beinahe allen Kontinenten von Minderheitengruppen gesprochen, unterliegt dort aber keinen gesetzlichen Bestimmungen.

Comment: Danke für die fein ausführliche Antwort. In etwa so, wie ich sie erwartet habe. Ich wäre für das frühe Deutschland (also alles vor 1933, eher sogar noch vor 1918) sowieso davon ausgegangen, dass Länder unter sich ihr eigenes Süppchen kochen, und demnach eine solchne Aussprache höchstens in dem einen oder anderen norddeutschen Teilstaat hätte gesetzlich festgelegt werden können.

Comment: Ich schließe mich der Vermutung an, daß die Siebssche Bühnenaussprache niemals irgendwo im deutschen Sprachraum für den Allgemeingebrauch gesetzlich vorgeschrieben worden ist. Ich würde das Zitat "damals teilweise gesetzlich verordnete Bühnensprache" allerdings auch nicht in dieser Weise interpretieren. Meines Erachtens bezieht sich "gesetzlich verordnet" hier auf die Verwendung *auf der Theaterbühne*. Eine gesetzliche Regelung der *Bühnensprache* ist etwas, was ich dem einen oder anderen Provinzfürsten Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts durchaus zutrauen würde.

Answer (score -3):

Soweit mir bekannt, war die Siebssche Bühnenaussprache – die hier wohl gemeint ist – nie gesetzlich, zum Beispiel von einer staatlichen Stelle für die allgemeine Bevölkerung, vorgeschrieben. Sie bildete für die Theaterbühnen und auch für Radio- und dann Fernsehsprecher_innen eine Art Referenznorm.

Comment: Können wir auf politische Schreibweisen, die nicht in Schulen gelehrt werden, bitte verzichten?

Comment: Ist das Dein Ernst? _Rude_? Aber nicht wirklich. Es erfüllt den selben Zweck ("All hail political correctness!") ohne jene zu beleidigen, die in korrekter Grammatik mehr als eine bloße Empfehlung sehen. Wenn man auf korrektes _Gendern_ Wert legt (was ich nicht tue) führt am Ausschreiben beider Formen für mich kein Weg vorbei. Binnen-I und Schlimmeres kann keine Lösung sein. In diesem Sinn meine (versuchte) Korrektur.

Comment: @Ingmar. Ja, es ist mein Ernst. Wenn jemand offensichtlich absichtlich vom Standard abweicht, sollte man das respektieren. Im übrigen gefällt mir die Schreibweise mit dem Unterstrich auch nicht.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Ja, in einem Kommentar, aber in einer Antwort hier auf SX nicht unbedingt.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Weil es offensichtlich Absicht war habe ich Abstand davon genommen es selbst zu korrigieren. Zumindest bis wir eine Metadiskussion hatten, die vielleicht eine GL-weite Konvention festschreibt.

Comment: @Ingmar et. al.: I started a discussion on meta: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/896/266 - feel invited.

Comment: Gelten die Downvotes eigentlich dem »Gender-Gap«, oder halten die Downvoter die Antwort selbst für falsch, d.h. irreführend? Falls letzteres, bitte eine eigene, widerlegende Antwort hinzugeben. Falls ersteres würde ich entdownvoten vorschlagen, weil Downvotes [sachlich falschen Antworten](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) vorbehalten bleiben sollten.

Comment: Dies hier ist ein Lehrforum für deutsche Sprache, insofern ist es legitim, an Antworten entsprechende Qualitätsanforderungen hinsichtlich der Rechtschreibung zu stellen. Abgesehen davon würde ich für den Gendergap alleine nicht downvoten, die Antwort an sich ist aber nicht gut, da sie keine Quellen heranbringt.